# Why do so many movies start at the end?

Tags: analysis

I've been surprised recently by how many movies open with the ending: This is referred to as the ["How We Got Here" trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HowWeGotHere). The link has quite a long list of movies, but here is a [top ten version](http://whatculture.com/film/10-movies-that-start-at-the-end) if you need a shorter refresher.
This trope seems to be used mostly in movies and seldom used in books.

What is the purpose or starting at the end? Is it to create suspense?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Obviously, opinion-prone questions are a constant nuisance on StackExchange. However, this question is specific to plot and story structure. This part of film-making is quite well-documented, with most plot structures based on the 3-act structure. It is from this field that I expect a fairly established answer to come from.
If all the answers are opinion-based, I will gladly remove my question.

Comment: I think the question is a good one at its core, however, I question the assertion that this technique is "predominantly used."  I'm sure there are plenty of movies that use this trope, but there are also *a lot of movies* in general.  I doubt this trope is used in most of them.

Comment: [**Foregone Conclusion**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForegoneConclusion)

Comment: Apologies. "Predominantly" was specifically referring to mediums where this technique is used, i.e., movies and not books. I've hopefully clarified that further in the latest revision. @Steve-O